# How do I get the ID of the current document in an Umbraco data editor?

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

I'm currently building a data type editor (inheriting from `AbstractDataEditor`) for Umbraco but I have encountered a problem that I don't know how to solve. Google is normally my friend, but not today...

How can I get the ID of the document that the property I'm currently editing belongs to?

In my naive attempts to solve this problem I've tried the `umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent()` method, but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer for my question on Twitter.

> string nodeid = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"];

Thanks to Sebastiaan Janssen ([@cultiv](https://twitter.com/#!/cultiv))